# The supremum of a set $A$

Tags: supremum-and-infimum

Does there exist a natural number $n$ for which there is a supremum of a set $$A = \{a\in\mathbb{Q}^+ | a^3+a\leq n^2\}$$ in the set of rational numbers?

Since $f(a) = a^3+a$ is increasing function for $a\in \mathbb{Q}^+$, set $A$ has upper bound $n^2$, so we need to solve $a^3+a=n^2$? Is there such $n$?

Comment: There is no consensus in whether $0$ is a natural number or not, so you should clarify that.

Comment: $a(a^2+1)$ is not a perfect square for integer $a>0$; $a^2+1$ and $a$ have no common factors and $a^2+1$ is not a perfect square. I think you can show that there's no rational solutions either.

Comment: I dont think its a matter for there being any such $n$ but of there being any such $a$.  Let $a = \frac pq;p,q \in \mathbb N; \gcd(p,q) = 1$ then we need $p^3 + pq^2= n^2q^3$ and .... well, we must have $q^3|p^3$ but $\gcd(p,q)=1$ so $q=1$ and we need natural $p=a$ were $a^3+a=n^2$.   I think as $a^3+a = a(a^2+1)$ and as  $\gcd(a,a^2+1) = 1$ then for $a(a^2+1)$ to be a perfect square we must have both $a$ an $a^2 +1$ be perfect square.  But if $a^2$ and $a^2+1$ are both squares the only solution is $a^2 = 0^2$ and $a^2 + 1=1^2$.  And thus $a=0$ and $a^3 + a = 0^2$ and $n = 0$.  (only case.)

Comment: @jjagmath  but $0 \not \in \mathbb Q^+$, right?  (actually I'm not sure there is consensus on *that* either).  If $a > 0$ then $a^3 + a > 0$ and so we can't have $n = 0$ whether or not $0$ is natural or not.  .... but maybe we should specify whether $\mathbb Q^+$ means "non-negative rationals" or "positive rationals"